# Login issue in grafana using default username and password

Tags: grafana

I am trying o login using admin/admin which is the default username and password. I am unable to log into grafana. any input is appreciated.
i am sharing the logs here. as soon a i start the grafana server and go to localhost:3000 i am getting the login page but i am unable to login using the default username and password.

```
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Starting Grafana                         logger=server version=6.6.0 commit=unknown-dev branch=master compiled=2020-01-29T16:58:34+0530
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Config loaded from                       logger=settings file=/usr/local/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Config loaded from                       logger=settings file=/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Config overridden from command line      logger=settings arg="default.paths.data=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana"
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Config overridden from command line      logger=settings arg="default.paths.logs=/usr/local/var/log/grafana"
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Config overridden from command line      logger=settings arg="default.paths.plugins=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana/plugins"
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Path Home                                logger=settings path=/usr/local/share/grafana
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Path Data                                logger=settings path=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Path Logs                                logger=settings path=/usr/local/var/log/grafana
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Path Plugins                             logger=settings path=/usr/local/var/lib/grafana/plugins
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Path Provisioning                        logger=settings path=/usr/local/share/grafana/conf/provisioning
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] App mode production                      logger=settings
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing SqlStore                    logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Connecting to DB                         logger=sqlstore dbtype=sqlite3
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Starting DB migration                    logger=migrator
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing HTTPServer                  logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing BackendPluginManager        logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing PluginManager               logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Starting plugin search                   logger=plugins
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing HooksService                logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing OSSLicensingService         logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing InternalMetricsService      logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing RemoteCache                 logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing QuotaService                logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing ServerLockService           logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing UserAuthTokenService        logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing RenderingService            logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing AlertEngine                 logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing DatasourceCacheService      logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing LoginService                logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing SearchService               logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing TracingService              logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing UsageStatsService           logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing CleanUpService              logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing NotificationService         logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing provisioningServiceImpl     logger=server
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Backend rendering via phantomJS          logger=rendering renderer=phantomJS
WARN[02-05|15:20:51] phantomJS is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You should consider migrating from phantomJS to grafana-image-renderer plugin. logger=rendering renderer=phantomJS
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] Initializing Stream Manager 
INFO[02-05|15:20:51] HTTP Server Listen                       logger=http.server address=[::]:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=
INFO[02-05|15:21:06] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=0 size=29 referer=
EROR[02-05|15:21:11] Invalid username or password             logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
INFO[02-05|15:21:11] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=401 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=21 size=42 referer=http://localhost:3000/login
INFO[02-05|15:23:28] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=0 size=29 referer=
EROR[02-05|15:23:35] Invalid username or password             logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
INFO[02-05|15:23:35] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=401 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=24 size=42 referer=http://localhost:3000/login
EROR[02-05|15:23:36] Invalid username or password             logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
INFO[02-05|15:23:36] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=401 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=22 size=42 referer=http://localhost:3000/login
EROR[02-05|15:23:36] Invalid username or password             logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
INFO[02-05|15:23:36] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=401 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=22 size=42 referer=http://localhost:3000/login
EROR[02-05|15:23:58] Invalid username or password             logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= error="Invalid Username or Password"
INFO[02-05|15:23:58] Request Completed                        logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=POST path=/login status=401 remote_addr=[::1] time_ms=0 size=42 referer=http://localhost:3000/login .
```